# Java 7 Swing Applet fails in the SortingFocusTraversalPolicy class with StackOverflow error

Tags: java, swing, applet

Starting from Java 7 they added a new method called getComponentDownCycle in the SortingFocusTraversalPolicy class. And now I have time after time a StachOverflow error.
Here is the stach trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.qwe.rty.swing.container.bootstrap.AppletBootstrap.bgInit(AppletBootstrap.java:291)
    at com.qwe.rty.swing.container.bootstrap.AppletBootstrap.access$1000(AppletBootstrap.java:46)
    at com.qwe.rty.swing.container.bootstrap.AppletBootstrap$BgInitThread$1.run(AppletBootstrap.java:715)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.qwe.rty.swing.container.bootstrap.AppletBootstrap$BgInitThread.run(AppletBootstrap.java:542)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.qwe.rty.swing.container.bootstrap.AppletBootstrap.bgInit(AppletBootstrap.java:212)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.EmbeddedFrame.getParent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.enumerateAndSortCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFocusTraversalCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultFocusManager.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentDownCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultFocusManager.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentDownCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultFocusManager.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentDownCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultFocusManager.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentDownCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultFocusManager.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentDownCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultFocusManager.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LegacyGlueFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentDownCycle(Unknown Source)...
```

It seems that jre goes into an infinite recursion while trying to get focused component.
Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() without javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source). It will solve this issue.